# Use Python string repr for object type check in decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I've written a logging decorator that logs the time a specific function takes to execute, along with some other information. I'd like to add to that specific information some things based upon input arguments.  So I've written this little chunk of code:

```
for var in args:
    if repr(type(var)) == '<class \'django.contrib.auth.models.User\'>':
        user_id = var.id
    elif repr(type(var)) == '<class \'someclass.models.Widget\'>':
        event_name = method.__name__ + ':' + var.key
```

It seems clunky, but the other option is to inherit django.contrib.auth.models.user and  someclass.models.Widget into the file.  My question is whether the way I've done it is right, the inheritance approach is right, or if I've missed something.

Comment: Why go through `repr`?  Why not use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) or [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass)?

Comment: Ideally you'd use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)  and import them

Comment: I'm curious about the balance between efficiency and code-connectedness, in this case. If the decorator is applied to a wide variety of code chunks, and required to inherit from those chunks the classes it is branching on....  Nevermind. I guess if I were to use this in enough places I'd just subclass it and split the code chunks apart.
Thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the dumb way to do this.  The smart way is:

```
for var in args:
    if type(var) == models.User:
        user_id = var.id
    elif type(var) == models.Widget:
        event_name = method.__name__ + ':' + var.key
```

And to inherit the appropriate sources for the models.

If you want your decorator to be more efficient and end up inheriting a ton of classes, it would make sense to instead have a primary abstract class and several subclasses.